# Extract inline nodes from HTML string with offset and length

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have an HTML string like so:

```html
Hello <b>beautiful <i>World</i></b>
```

rendering to:

> Hello **beautiful *World***

I would like to split content and formatting resulting in a dictionary which has the text without any HTML tags and the inline tags separated and denoted by their `type`, `offset` and `length`. Here, `offset` would be the number of characters from the beginning of `text` regardless of all other inline nodes.

```py
{
  "text": "Hello beautiful World"
  "inlines": [
    {
      "type": "B",
      "offset": 6,
      "length": 15
    },{
      "type": "I",
      "offset": 16,
      "length": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Getting the clean `text`, of course, is simple using the fantastic [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), e.g.:

```py
import lxml.html as lhtml
lhtml.fromstring(text).text_content
```

Inline nodes could be extracted by iterating the characters of the string checking for the existence of a node at every character index. I wonder though, whether there is a more elegant (and most likely performant) to that approach.

Comment: For asking performance questions, a tested and measured implementation to compare against/improve on is required. Without a reference implementation of your own, the performance question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a more elegant solution.

```
from lxml import html

string = 'Hello <b>beautiful <i>World</i></b>'

root = html.fromstring(string)

result = {}
result['text'] = root.text_content()

inlines = []
for element in root.xpath('.//*'):
    tag_type = element.tag.upper()
    length = len(element.text_content())
    offset = len(''.join(element.xpath('./preceding::text()')))
    inlines.append({'type': tag_type, 'offset': offset, 'length': length})

result['inlines'] = inlines

print(result)
```